# how to save datetime with milliseconds in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to save datetime value with minutes,seconds and milliseconds in sharepoint 2010 list column.

I tried but my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

SPFieldDateTime doesn't allow to store milliseconds so you will have to create your own SPFieldType ([look here for help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861799%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) or you just have to store your DateTime into a SPFieldText field and process the stored information as needed. You would loose the Datepicker control, but since you require such exact results, that doesn't seem to be a problem.